# Actualizar un JTextArea - Constantemente

Tags: java

Muy Buenas a todos,
Tengo un inconveniente en cuanto a cambiar valores constantemente de un JTextArea, lo unico que quiero es que al cambiar varias veces el valor del componente con su metodo .setText(); lo remplace Y lo muestre efectivamente, pero solamente me toma siempre el ultimo valor. Esta accion la hago mediante un ActionListener a un boton que llama al metodo que hace el remplazo constante. 
Esto lo hago como ejemplo rapido, ya que mi intencion es llamar un metodo en una clase distinta donde en ese JTextArea me tome una futura barra de carga... pero si no puedo si quiera cambiar el valor de este constantemente no podre hacer lo siguiente... Agradezco mucho la ayuda.[image: Imagen Con Codigo]

Comment: por que no usar ProgressBar altiro?

Comment: Estoy aprendiendo a usar cada componente,  y pues mi idea es hacer una barra de progreso tipo consola en Linux que solamente va agregando un caracter hacia la derecha, 'esto en consola ya lo hice' pero en JText no lo logro. He leido que puede ser porque se bloquea la interfaz al hacer una tarea, pero por eso mismo estoy separando cada tarea y ni asi...

Comment: Para que le das Thread.sleep(1000); al hilo?

Comment: Para que haga una pausa de 1 segundo, asi "si hiciera el cambio" podria ver primero en pantalla Cargando, luego cargando 2 y por ultimo cargando 3.Pero no lo hace

Comment: Pero es una simulación de conteo o de carga o en verdad estas haciendo un proceso en el que tiene que detener el hilo?

Comment: Es un proceso corriendo, donde si no se detiene seguiria 'remplazando el contenido del JTextArea' indefinidamente, lo que bloquearia el Thread sin poder avanzar. Solo se esta cambiando el valor del JTextArea una y otra vez para poder mostrarse en pantalla pero no se muestran, si no solo el final.

Answer (score 0):

El error puede estar en los `Thread.Sleep` ya que esto bloquea el hilo principal del programa ([EDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)) , si de verdad necesitas usar `Thread.Sleep` prueba con el siguiente metodo:

```
       //RESTO DEL CODIGO
       campocarga.setText("Cargando");
       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
           campocarga.setText("Cargando 2");
       }, 2000);

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
           campocarga.setText("Cargando 3");
       }, 2000);
       //RESTO DEL CODIGO
```

Answer (score 0):

Indagando un poco, encontre que en efecto si uno usa el hilo que tiene la interfaz grafica para otra cosa, esto hace que la misma interfaz se bloquee y en Android por lo menos es una muy mala practica utilizar el hilo grafico para otra cosa que no sea el libre flujo de esta, por lo tanto vi que lo mejor era dividir cada proceso en Hilos apartes... Lo probe y logre hacer que se ejecuten varios procesos mientras la interfaz se actualiza correctamente en tiempo real. La clase Handlear como me lo explican arriba tambien sirve para hacer algo muy parecido ya que inicia otro hilo pero se utiliza para algunas cosillas en especifico. Pero tambien es una muy buena solucion para mi problema inicial :D... Muchas gracias.

[image: Solucion de Interfaz Bloqueada]